# Glob match recursive delete directories except a certain directory

Tags: bash, shell, rm

How can I delete all directories recursively where the name starts with `app-deployment-*` except a particular directory with name `app-deployment-245a578`. I.E. delete all directories using a glob match but don't delete a particular known named directory.

```
rm -rf app-deployment-* # except app-deployment-245a578
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 \
        -type d \
        -name 'app-deployment-*' \
        ! -name 'app-deployment-245a578' \
        -exec echo rm -rf {} +
```

Explanations:

- `-maxdepth 1` mean without recursion;
- `-type d` mean search only for directories;
- `-name 'app-deployment-*'` is a pattern of directories you are searching for;
- `! -name 'app-deployment-245a578'` is a pattern of directories you are excluding from result list
  Repeat it multiple times if you want to exlude multiple directories;
- `exec echo rm -rf` -- execute a command `echo rm -rf`;
- `{} +` -- add search results as a parameters to the command above.
  Directory names will be added like that: `echo rm -rf dir1 dir2 dir3`.

About the last point. If you want to call the command with each param separately (I mean `echo rm -rf dir1; echo rm -rf dir2;`), you should write `{} \;` (note the backslash) instead of `{} +`.

About the command. I write `echo rm -rf` instead of `rm -rf` due to all the danger of using `rm -rf` with any kind of pattern matching. Be careful and check everything before removing `echo` from the command.

Futher reading about danger of rm + patterns: [Creative uses of rm](http://www.softpanorama.org/Admin/Horror_stories/creative_uses_of_rm.shtml)

**UPD:** worth noting that `{} +` should be at the end of command, i.e. you can't use `-exec rm {} + -rf`

Comment: Good explanation.